# Sumar total en una tabla dinamica

Tags: html, jquery, python-2.7, tabla-dinámica

Estoy recién empezando en esto y necesito sumar los totales de todos los vendedores alguien me puede ayudar aquí esta el html

```html
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="rh_empleado">Nombre Empleado</th>
      <th data-field="monto_neto">Monto</th>
      <th data-field="ver">Ver</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for d in dato %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ d['vendedor'] }}</td>
      <td class="total">{{ "{:,.0f}".format(d["monto_neto"]) }}</td>
      <td><a class="button" href="Vendedor/{{ d['cod_vendedor'] }}"
        ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
<tr>
  <td>Total:</td>
  <td id="total"></td>
<tr>
```

y mi script es:

```js
var total=0;
$(".total").each(function(){
 total+=parseFloat($(this).html()) || 0;
});
```

Comment: Bienvenido @MatiasCaceres a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A no ser que quieras que la suma se haga en el cliente, lo más simple es que la calcule el servidor. No dices qué *framework* estás usando, pero supongo que funcionaría algo así:

```
<tr>
  <td>Total:</td>
  <td id="total">{{ sum(d["monto_neto"] for d in dato) }}</td>
<tr>
```

Dependiendo del framework, es casi seguro que cuente con algún filtro o *pipe* para hacer la suma. Por ejemplo, con jinja (en django):

```
{{ dato|sum(attribute='monto_neto') }}
```

Comment: Excelente esa era la función que necesitaba muchas gracias ! funciono de maravilla

Comment: Si la respuesta funcionó @MatiasCaceres sugiero que sea acepta, [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas) esto no sólo aumentará tus puntos y la posibilidad de que ganes más medallas, sino que permitirá a la comunidad estar enfocada en ayudar a otros miembros con las preguntas no resueltas.